# Python - writing to a textfile on the same line

Tags: python, io, text-files

I'm currently concatenating a variable and string together, with the aim of writing it to a textfile. However, once I've joined it together, it doesn't write to the textfile on the same line. I've copied in the code below;

```
x = f.readlines()

g = open('workfile.txt','w')
for ux in x:
    um = str.join('@', (str(ux), 'server'))
    g.writelines(str(um)+'\n')
```

When I open the textfile, I get the following result:

```
User
@server
Nint
@server
Loot
@server
```

Would really appreciate any help! Thanks!

Comment: How was ```f``` opened? binary or text?

Answer (score 0):

`ux` may contain a newline, you can try

```
g = open('workfile.txt','w')
for ux in x:
    um = str.join('@', (str(ux).strip(), 'server'))
    g.writelines(str(um)+'\n')
```